# How to add external js file in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created one js file in our application. in this js file How add in our page?

I had Written below code for our application. First of  I had written online link that's work perfect. then after download js and set path to js file. but not proper working.

```
componentDidMount() {
const script = document.createElement("script");
// script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js";
script.src = "../../Content/JS/jquery-1.12.4.min.js";
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

}

Comment: install those packages by `npm install {package name}`

Comment: which one package install ??

Comment: as i can see you want to use Jquery in project then you can install it by `npm install --save jquery` or through your package manager

Comment: I have already install this package. but can't add to external js file.

Comment: put js file within src folder and import this file and put it in script tag anywhere inside your project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add additional js file (script). This is the easiest way to to do this.

```
<body>
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="../../Content/JS/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is the root html file of your react application. According to your folder structure path can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and then import jQuery or any other plugin you need in your component.

```
npm install {package name}
```

in your package JSON.

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
```

in your component

Here is an [`example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j5vacz)